# Could someone explain the differences here?

Tags: android

When I want to get result from start activity, I will use method `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`.

What is the difference if I pass 0 (zero) as the second parameter and if pass -1 (negative one) as the parameter?

Comment: Isn't it obvious from the documentation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is if you pass a value >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits and your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity.

Otherwise, it is the same as calling startActivity(Intent). (the activity is not launched as a sub-activity)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> As a special case, if you call startActivityForResult() with a requestCode >= 0 during the initial onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)/onResume() of your activity, then your window will not be displayed until a result is returned back from the started activity. This is to avoid visible flickering when redirecting to another activity.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass 0, the method will return 0 in onActivityResult() when the activity completes.

If you pass -1, I don't believe any value will be passed (according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), the value will only be returned if it is >= 0)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when `onActivityResult` method gets called back, its `requestCode` parameter will be either 0 or -1.

Comment: LOL, I know that. What is the meaning of -1? I think 0 equals to RESULT.OK, but I am not sure.